# Android client finding C# server automatically

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets, networking

My Android client is trying to find C# server in the network...

This is **the procedure**:
0. Server is listening for the UDP packet
1. Client sends UDP packet and starts listening for response
2. Server receive UDP packet, and if packet is sent by client, server is sending new UDP packet to client
3. Client receive UDP packet

**C# server code:**

```
//receive UDP packet
                    int port = (int)float.Parse(Variables.port_key);
                    UdpClient UDP_receive = new UdpClient(port);
                    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                    IPAddress from_addr = null;
                    Boolean gogo = false;
                    ExecuteCommand("Receiving...");
                    while (!gogo)
                    {
                        Byte[] receiveBytes = UDP_receive.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                        string returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes);
                        if (returnData.ToString() == "83hcX1")
                        {
                            gogo = true;
                        }
                        from_addr = RemoteIpEndPoint.Address;
                        ExecuteCommand("Package received: " + returnData.ToString());
                    }
                    ExecuteCommand("Out of loop");
                    UDP_receive.Close();
                    ExecuteCommand("UDP_receive closed");
                    //send UDP packet
                    UdpClient UDP_send = new UdpClient();
                    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(from_addr, port);
                    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("94dbF5");
                    UDP_send.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, ipEndPoint);
                    ExecuteCommand("Package sent");
                    UDP_send.Close();
                    ExecuteCommand("UDP_send closed");
```

**This is the result:**
Receiving...
Package received: 83hcX1
Out of loop
UDP_receive closed
Package sent
UDP_send closed

> (So... I think that servers code is OK...)

Now the
**android.java client code:**
PS. this code is executed automatically after the app starts.

```
int port = SERVERPORT;
                    //send UDP packet
                    DatagramSocket UDP_send = new DatagramSocket();
                    byte[] b = "83hcX1".getBytes("UTF-8");
                    DatagramPacket outgoing = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, getBroadcastAddress(Main.this), port);                    
                    UDP_send.send(outgoing);
                    Log.e("UDP", "Package sent");
                    UDP_send.close();
                    Log.e("UDP", "UDP_send closed");
                    //receive UDP packet
                    DatagramSocket UDP_receive = new DatagramSocket(port);
                    boolean gogo = false;
                    Log.e("UDP", "Receiving...");
                    while (!gogo) {                     
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
                        DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);                    
                        UDP_receive.receive(incoming);
                        String message = new String(incoming.getData(), 0, incoming.getLength(), "UTF-8");
                         Log.e("Received", incoming.getPort() + "" + incoming.getAddress() + message);
                         if (message.equals("94dbF5")) {
                            Log.e("UDP", "Same");                           
                             gogo = true;
                         }else {
                            Log.e("UDP", "Not same!");
                         }                      
                    }
                    Log.e("UDP", "I'm out of loop");                
                    UDP_receive.close();
                    Log.e("UDP", "UDP_receive closed");
```

**Result:**
After first start:
07-10 22:35:04.017: E/UDP(4638): Package sent
07-10 22:35:04.027: E/UDP(4638): UDP_send closed
07-10 22:35:04.047: E/UDP(4638): Receiving...

If I restart app I get this:
07-10 22:45:05.327: E/Received(4638): 42283/192.168.3.1883hcX1
07-10 22:45:05.327: E/UDP(4638): Package sent
07-10 22:45:05.327: E/UDP(4638): UDP_send closed
07-10 22:45:05.347: E/UDP(4638): Not same!
07-10 22:45:05.347: E/UDP(4638): java.net.BindException: Address already in use

If I restart app and server:
07-10 22:47:36.447: E/Received(4638): 57895/192.168.3.1883hcX1
07-10 22:47:36.467: E/UDP(4638): Not same!
07-10 22:47:36.477: E/UDP(4638): Package sent
07-10 22:47:36.477: E/UDP(4638): UDP_send closed
07-10 22:47:36.487: E/Received(4638): **61420/192.168.3.1094dbF5**
07-10 22:47:36.497: E/UDP(4638): java.net.BindException: Address already in use
07-10 22:47:36.507: E/UDP(4638): Same
07-10 22:47:36.507: E/UDP(4638): I'm out of loop
07-10 22:47:36.527: E/UDP(4638): UDP_receive closed

I know that I'm doing something wrong related to ports (because I get java.net.BindException: Address already in use - error), but what??
Why do I get the result I want (**61420/192.168.3.1094dbF5**) only after second start of app and server?

Comment: I think you mean UDP *packet*.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
This is a working example:

**C# server**

```
                    //receive UDP packet
                    int port = (int)float.Parse(Variables.port_key);
                    UdpCient UDP_packet = new UdpClient(port);
                    UDP_packet.EnableBroadcast = true;
                    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                    IPAddress from_addr = null;
                    Boolean gogo = false;
                    while (!gogo)
                    {
                        Byte[] receiveBytes = UDP_packet.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                        string returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes);
                        if (returnData.ToString() == "83hcX1")
                        {
                            gogo = true;
                        }
                        from_addr = RemoteIpEndPoint.Address;
                    }
                    //send UDP packet
                    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(from_addr, port);
                    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("94dbF5");
                    UDP_packet.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, ipEndPoint);
                    UDP_packet.Close();
```

**Android client**

```
                        //send UDP packet
                        DatagramSocket UDP_packet = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);
                        UDP_packet.setBroadcast(true);
                        byte[] b = "83hcX1".getBytes("UTF-8");
                        DatagramPacket outgoing = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, getBroadcastAddress(Main.this), SERVERPORT);                  
                        UDP_packet.send(outgoing);
                        //receive UDP packet
                        boolean gogo = false;
                        while (!gogo) {                     
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);    
                            UDP_packet.receive(incoming);
                            String message = new String(incoming.getData(), 0, incoming.getLength(), "UTF-8");
                             if (message.equals("94dbF5")) {
                                 gogo = true;
                                 SERVER_IP = incoming.getAddress();
                             }                  
                        }               
                        UDP_packet.close();
```

Now you can connect to server address (SERVER_IP).
Also, I read that some routers (maybe 5%) block UDP broadcast, so... be careful.

If someone see any error, please post it.

**EDIT:**

```
InetAddress getBroadcastAddress(Context context) throws IOException {
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
        if (dhcp == null) {
              return null;
            }
        int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
        byte[] quads = new byte[4];
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
          quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
    }
```